# Add existing fields to nested schema

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents in my db with schema:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
  Street: { type: String },
  Age: { type: Number, default: null },
  Date: { type: Date },
  Stuff: [
       {
        _id:false, 
        ThisDate: { type: Date },
        ThisStreet: { type: String }
       }]
});
```

Right now it is (`Stuff` is empty):

```
db.person.findOne()  
    {
      Street: 'TheStreet',
      Age: 23,
      Date: ISODate("2016-02-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
      Stuff: []
    }
```

I then want to update all documents. What I want to do is to move `Street` and `Date` fields into `Stuff` array and delete `Street` and `Date` fields from schema.

Like this:

```
db.person.findOne()  
    {
      Age: 23,
      Stuff : [ 
      {
        ThisDate : ISODate("2016-02-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
        ThisStreet : "TheStreet"
      }
      ]
    }
```

How could I achieve this?
Best Regards

Comment: Update your post with sample document. Also what do you meant by update all documents? Do you mean that you want to move street and date fields into array?

Comment: @Saleem the first `db.person.findOne() ` is sample document. Yes move street and date into Stuff array.

Comment: Great. Please see my post below. I'm using aggregation framework to transform document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a "one off" operation I would do it in the shell rather than use any other framework.

For MongoDB 3.2.x releases and greater use, [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/):

```js
var ops = [];

db.person.find({ 
    "Street": { "$exists": true },
    "Date": { "$exists": true }
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": {
                "$unset": {
                    "Street": "",
                    "Date": ""
                },
                "$set": {
                    "Stuff": [{
                        "ThisDate": doc.Date,
                        "ThisStreet": doc.Street
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
        db.person.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 )
    db.person.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Or for MongoDB 2.6.x and 3.0.x releases use this version of Bulk operations:

```js
var bulk = db.person.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.person.find({ 
    "Street": { "$exists": true },
    "Date": { "$exists": true }
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$unset": {
            "Street": "",
            "Date": ""
        },
        "$set": {
            "Stuff": [{
                "ThisDate": doc.Date,
                "ThisStreet": doc.Street
            }]
        }
    });

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.person.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Bottom line is that you need to iterate the documents in the collection and write them back with the re-arranged content "one by one". At least the Bulk operations API in use in both cases will reduce the load of writing and responding with the server to only one in every 1000 documents in the collection to process.

Also, rather than rewriting the whole document you are using [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to remove the desired fields and [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to write "just" the data you want

---

### Working example

```js
db.person.insert(
    {
      "Street": 'TheStreet',
      "Age": 23,
      "Date": ISODate("2016-02-19T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "Stuff": []
    }
)
```

Then after running either pdate above the result is:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56e607c1ca8e7e3519b4ce93"),
        "Age" : 23,
        "Stuff" : [
                {
                        "ThisDate" : ISODate("2016-02-19T00:00:00Z"),
                        "ThisStreet" : "TheStreet"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: @user1665355 Second listing covers releases 2.6.x and 3.0.x. `bulkWrite()` was introduced in 3.2.

Comment: I will try it! :) Thanks! Accept as soon I see it works!

Comment: Is it possible to use `replace` javascript command in mongodb shell? Trying but that does not work.

Comment: @user1665355 Just run the listing as it is here. There are reasons why it is done this way, mostly since it's the most efficient and safe way.

Comment: It seems to work but I get : `2016-03-13T11:18:56.577+0100 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>     bulk.execute();
` in shell. Any ideas why?

Comment: @user1665355 There was a comma instead of a semi-colon in the listing

Comment: Accepted your answer:)

Comment: @user1665355 You cannot be running the code as it is presented as it works perfectly for me. Not exactly the first time I have ever written this either! Added the output, just as expected when I run either un-altered listing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to transform document using aggregation framework and update as described in code snippet below

```
db.person.aggregate([
{$project:{Age:1, Stuff:[{Date:"$Date", Street:"$Street"}]}}
]).forEach(function(o){
  var id = o._id;
  delete o._id;
  db.person.update({_id:id, Street:{$exists: true}},o);
});
```

After successful execution, you document or documents should look like

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e2cd45792861e14df1f0a9"), 
    "Age" : 23.0, 
    "Stuff" : [
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2016-02-19T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "Street" : "TheStreet"
        }
    ]
}
```